Expanding and Reducing only width image size velo framework
I am currently using Wix studio with the velo framework.
I have an image I would like to smoothly expand by 70% when it is hovered over, and reduce by 50% when it is not being hovered over.
I am encountering issues with the image.style.width not being available to produce this type of animation .

You want to use the wix-animations API instead of changing the width directly. So something like this:
import { timeline } from 'wix-animations-frontend'

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w('#myImage').onMouseIn(() => {
        timeline()
            .add($w('#myImage'), {duration: 2000, scale: 1.7, easing: 'easeInCubic'})
            .play()
    })

    $w('#myImage').onMouseOut(() => {
        timeline()
            .add($w('#myImage'), {duration: 2000, scale: 1.5, easing: 'easeOutCubic'})
            .play()
    })
})

